# making a virtualbox vm (debian/linux) act as a router?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I would like to know what are the steps to make a vm (I am using a debian/linux machine) act as a router/forward traffic between two networks in virtualbox. I am trying to create a virtual network with a bunch of systems. I would like one of the machines to route traffic between two subnets.

I have started of with configuring multiple interfaces and adding internal networks on these interfaces. I am not sure if I should add some rules to my vm to make it work like a router and forward packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install your virtual router as if it were a metal router. The host will have network cards for each network but most likely the external network will be isolated through iptables (firestarter is an easy way to configure this). The guest will get connected to those networks as bridged adapters. The host must have a valid connection to each network (valid address or similar) just to have the adapter up an working. Note that iptables filtering for the host occurs after redirection by vbox connection, so iptables affect the host only, and the guest will have to use its own security. You can use Internal networks to generate virtualized networks to connect several hosts.